# Error "enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'" docker referencing to external folder

Tags: node.js, docker

I have my whole `nodejs` code in `abc` folder

```
root@ip-10-0-0-9:~/standalone/apiserver# ls
Dockerfile  abc
root@ip-10-0-0-9:~/standalone/apiserver/abc# ls
build  index.html  node_modules  package.json  package-lock.json  src
```

I have created Dockerfile in following manner:

```
FROM node:10
#Create app directory
WORKDIR /app
COPY abc/package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

When i am running my docker container in following way,it gives error:

```
docker build -t node-app .

root@ip-10-0-0-9:~/standalone/apiserver# docker run -it   --net=host   -v /abc:/app   --name mynodeapp1 node-app
npm ERR! path /app/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-05-14T14_36_09_651Z-debug.log
```

Update:

Contents of package.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "utkarsh",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/server.js",
    "lint": "eslint **/*.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "mysql": "^2.15.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.14.12"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to bind the directory /abc from your host machine inside the container? Note: /abc is different the ./abc, your issue might be trying to bind /abc to /app and /app getting overwritten with nothing when binding it.

Comment: @callmeroot I am binding it while running "run" command.

Comment: Right. I understand that. But is the directory /abc what you want to bind?  Or do you want to bind the abc sudirectory of your apiserver directory (apiserver/abc)?

Comment: @callmeroot I want to bind abc...

Comment: Can you try to use this command to run: 
docker run -it --net=host -v "$(pwd)"/abc:/app --name mynodeapp1 node-app

Comment: @UtkarshSaraf what was your solution?

Answer (score 4):

I've modified your `Dockerfile` a bit, and it seems to work now here.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10
#Create app directory
WORKDIR /app
COPY abc/package*.json ./
RUN ls -al
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

You can remove the `RUN ls -al`, I've only put it there to see the contents of the `workdir`, and it printed the files.

The change is - you've already specified where all the work should be done, by setting `WORKDIR`, based on that I relate to the path you set, when `COPY`'ing there.

Try if it works and post back ;)

Comment: can you post the build log?

Comment: How can I enter into container post termination.

Comment: How can I enter into container post termination.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I mean, you cannot, do you want to do it to check the logs I asked about?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact error and it turned out to be an issue with docker-compose. For me I'm running WSL in windows and the version of docker-compose installed inside WSL was not handling volume binding correctly. I fixed this by uninstalling `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose` and instead aliasing the windows exe `alias docker-compose="/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin/docker-compose.exe"`

If you are not on windows try to [update your version of docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact issue using docker-compose with Docker for Windows. Was able to resolve it by hitting "Reset credentials" and reapplying checkboxes for the needed drives.

[image: Docker Reset credentials screen]